# Updating resources but is idempotent, can httpGet be used or post

Tags: rest, http

I read posts and did research on rest call. However I cant figure out this particular situation.
I don't know if I should be using Get or Post.

I have a service call that update the database (unlocking a record, changing a flag to false). It's changing the data in database, however no matter how many times you call this service, the change will only happen once, even if you unlock the record three times, the state will still be unlock, so Idempotent.

So that means I can use Get for this instead of post? but can I use Get when I am updating data in the database?

The service call also only take in one Id, I want to add it to the query parameter instead of the body, it would be weird to use post without body right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All `GET` requests should be *safe*. This means that doing a GET request should have no consequences to the state of your database.

Usually when a resource is changed, `PUT` is used. `POST` is also ok. It doesn't matter that POST is not guaranteed to be idempotent. If it does in some cases (like yours) it doesn't break the spec.

However, it sounds like in your case `PUT` is more appropriate.